# Replace empty method with method from a class where it is used

Tags: java

In the following scenario, I want to replace Class B's (similarly D, E, F, etc.) method doSomething() with the method in Class A where it will be used. How would I go about this? Made up some example, hope it gets the message across

```
public class B implements GetNames{
   public void getNameA(){ return "NameA"; }
   public void getNameB() { return "NameB"; }
   public void doStuff(){
      //print names
      doSomething(getNameA(), getNameB());
      //print names
   }
   public void doSomething(String a, String b){}

}

public class A{
   public void someMethod(){
       B b = new B();
       b.doStuff(); //*So I want it to call the method in B but somehow replace the doSomething method in B with the doSomething method in A
   }

   public void doSomething(String a, String b){
       //print 'blabla' + a
       //print 'blablabla' + b
       //concatenate and print
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you inherit `B` and override it?

Comment: The example does not make sense. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `GetNames` is a terrible name for an interface. Work on that!

Comment: try using inheritance

Comment: If you need to call doSomething() in a multiple classes (B, C, D, ...) /always/, you can inherit A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made `abstract` class A implement interface `GetNames` and then extend it in class B:

```
public abstract class A implements GetNames {
   public void doSomething(String a, String b){
       //print 'blabla' + a
       //print 'blablabla' + b
       //concatenate and print
   }
}

public class B extends A {
   public void getNameA(){ return "NameA"; }
   public void getNameB() { return "NameB"; }
   public void doStuff(){
      // class A's doSomething will be called
      doSomething(getNameA(), getNameB());
      //print names
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` should extend class `B`.  If you make `B` an abstract class, the `B.java` file would look something like this:

```
public abstract class B {
    ...
    public abstract void doSomething(String a, String b);
    ...
}
```

An abstract class has some functionality, like the `getNameA` method, which is already defined, but other methods like `doSomething` are left to its subclasses to implement.

Change class A to read:

```
public class A extends B {
    ...
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String a, String b) {
        // custom behaviour
    }
}
```

If what you want is to just make an instance of class `B` that has a different implementation of the method `doSomething` then what you could do is this:

```
B myBInstance = new B() {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String a, String b) {
        // custom behaviour here
    }
};

myBInstance.doStuff();
```

Style-wise and design-wise though, this is only a quick-and-dirty way to define behaviour for a one-time use of `B`.